# LEFT JOIN (or similar) on a single-column table to get whether each row is in other table or not

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Here's the situation. I have two sets of data. One is a list of all the "ticket" entries that my system uses – at least one per ID, but potentially more. I also have a separate list of just the IDs that have known hardware problems, which is a relatively small (but important) subset of the IDs. I've put this list into a super-simple table B, which is literally a single column with just those IDs.

I need a MySQL query that joins these two tables, so I get all of the entries from table A, each of which has another field added on that is a simple boolean: whether or not the same ID exists in table B.

So something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_A` A
LEFT JOIN `table_B` B ON A.id=B.id
```

If B were a two-column table, and the second column (call it `down`) was simply `true` in every row, then I could check if `down` were `true` or `null`.

But since B has only a single column, no data is actually added to the result.

Is there any simple way (without having this otherwise completely unnecessary column in my database) to do this "join" operation, that will simply note whether or not the ID of a given entry in A also exists in B?

(adding another field to A that is up or down is also rather inefficient, since there are often many rows for a single ID and most IDs aren't going to be down anyway)

Comment: TableB's ID will be NULL if there is no match.

Comment: Try this:

SELECT * FROM A WHERE ID IN
(SELECT ID FROM B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the example below 'down' will not be null if the id exists in table_B

```
SELECT * , B.id as `down` FROM `table_A` A
LEFT JOIN `table_B` B ON A.id=B.id
```

Comment: Written just as you have it, I get `Invalid table_A query: Unknown column 'table_B.id' in 'field list'`. Trying `count(B.id)` instead just returns no rows...

Comment: I did that originally; that returned zero rows.

Comment: Aha, that does it too! I'm going to accept yours even though @Clodoaldo's answer also works, since yours is easier to read/write.

Comment: you thought of changing the name of id in table B

Comment: I what? No, I didn't. The only thing I tried on my own was changing `count(table_B.id)` to `count(B.id)`. Which didn't work. The `B.id as down` worked great though.

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
    A.*, 
    case when B.ID is null then 0 else 1 end as myBoolean
from `table_A` A
    left join `table_B` B on A.ID = B.ID
```